# How can I add an animation in a table layout in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a table that contains rows with image and text. Now, I decided to exchange the image with a rotation animation. Is there a way to do this in a table or do I have to use `SpriteBatch` to accomplish this? If yes, is there a way to keep my table and somehow find the correct position of that row/column that the image was in?
I'm reluctant to get rid of the table because there's a large portion of text. And it makes it much easier with the `setWrap` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can wrap all animation stuff in a Group. Now insert that Group in the table which will manage location of the group.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the group also requires Actors (which an Animation isn't). It works with the Image because an Image extends from the Actor class but not an Animation. So how could I add an animation to a group?

Comment: You can always override draw method, that way you get access to spritebatch, and rest is easy.

Comment: Thanks, that worked: I ended up creating my own `Actor` class and overriding the `draw()` method to draw the animation and `act(float delta)` method to update the state time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load everything at the beginning in the constructor

```
private void loadTextures() {
    walkSheet = new  Texture(Gdx.files.internal("animation_sheet.png"));
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet, walkSheet.getWidth() / 
            FRAME_COLS, walkSheet.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS);
    walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
                    walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
            }
    }
    walkAnimation = new Animation(0.025f, walkFrames);

    stateTime = 0f;

    bobTexture = new  Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/bob.png"));
    blockTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/block.png"));
}
```

This is the method would look like that draws sprite:

```
private void drawBob() {
        Bob bob = world.getBob();

        int facex=1;
        if(bob.facingLeft){
            facex=-1;
        }

        if (bob.state==bob.state.WALKING){
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, bob.position.x * ppuX, bob.position.y * ppuY, facex*Bob.SIZE * ppuX, Bob.SIZE * ppuY);

        }
        else if(bob.state==bob.state.IDLE){
            spriteBatch.draw(bobTexture, bob.position.x * ppuX, bob.position.y * ppuY, facex* Bob.SIZE * ppuX, Bob.SIZE * ppuY);
        }

            //spriteBatch.draw(bobTexture, bob.position.x * ppuX, bob.position.y * ppuY, Bob.SIZE * ppuX, Bob.SIZE * ppuY);

    }
```

Just don't forget to begin sprite batch before calling it.

```
  public void render() {
     spriteBatch.begin();
            drawBlocks();
            drawBob();
     spriteBatch.end();

        if (debug)
            drawDebug();
      }
```

The full code can be found here in my re-blog:
http://www.sadafnoor.com/blog/adding-animation-on-character-movement-using-libgdx/

Comment: I know how to draw animations using `SpriteBatch`. My question was if it's possible to still use the table.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use it:
(Code as is, no warranty)

Implement your own Actor that can display Animations:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;

/**
 * nils honermann (zeg)
 * - no warranty, free to use
 */
public class GdxAnimationActor extends Actor {

    private Animation animation;

    public void dispose(){
        for(TextureRegion tr : animation.getKeyFrames()){
            tr.getTexture().dispose();
        }
        animation = null;
    }

    public GdxAnimationActor(Animation animation){
        this.animation=animation;
        TextureRegion first = animation.getKeyFrame(0f);
        setBounds(first.getRegionX(),first.getRegionY(),first.getRegionWidth(),first.getRegionHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        // TODO: Should be multiplied with the actor's alpha, allowing a parent's alpha to affect all children.

        TextureRegion current = animation.getKeyFrame(elapsed/1000.0f/*millis into seconds float*/);
        batch.draw(current,getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation());

        if(renderedOnce){
            elapsed += System.currentTimeMillis() - millisLastRender;
        }
        millisLastRender = System.currentTimeMillis();
        renderedOnce = true;
    }

    private float elapsed = 0;
    private boolean renderedOnce;
    private long millisLastRender = 0;
}
```

and pass your animation into it.

```
float fps = 0.1f; //1 texture per 100 millis
Array<TextureRegion> textureArray = new Array<>(3);
textureArray.size = 3;
textureArray.set( (0) , new TextureRegion(new Texture(/*assets*/"example1.png");) );
textureArray.set( (1) , new TextureRegion(new Texture(/*assets*/"example2.png");) );
textureArray.set( (2) , new TextureRegion(new Texture(/*assets*/"example3.png");) );
Animation animation = new Animation(fps,textureArray,Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
GdxAnimationActor animationActor = new GdxAnimationActor(animation);
```

just add your animationActor to your stage, a window or a table for example.